# Can Google Analytics be used in Instant Games?

Tags: facebook-instant-games

I know that Facebook Analytics exists, but that doesn't seem to offer info on real-time traffic. Can Google Analytics be added or is it against the policy of Instant Games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics can be used and many developers use it today, though Facebook Analytics can be used for some limited realtime insights.

Comment: Thanks! I use Facebook Analytics for stats relating to the platform itself. However, it's kind of useful to have a figure of how many users are on it in real-time.